# Custom Touch ID view

Tags: ios, ios8, touch-id

Is it possible to listen for a positive fingerprint match without the default Touch ID view? I want to create a log-in view where *both* a pin keyboard and Touch ID are available at the same time (without having to choose one or the other).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No the iOS SDK only allows you access the touch ID via the `LAContext` [`evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/LAContext/evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:)